# Is "strongly" an acceptable adverb for the verb "transfer"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adverbs

Is it acceptable to say

> This determines how strongly heat is transferred from A to B.

?

[One of the definitions](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/strongly?q=strongly) of "strongly" is

> to a great degree or extent

So the answer to the question above seems to be yes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not “wrong” to refer to how **strongly** heat is transferred, but it doesn’t fit well here. It has a different meaning that is not commonly applied to a transfer. When we describe a *process* we are more likely to talk about how **well**, how **completely** or how **quickly** the process occurs, not how **strongly** it occurs. We are usually discussing “degree” not discussing “strength”.

For example, strongly is not a good substitute for the words in bold in these sentences:

> How **well** does heat transfer through water?
>
> Does stirring influence how **completely** the crystals dissolve?
>
> The temperature influences how **well** the concrete sets overnight.
>
> Warm days change how **quickly** the green leaves turn orange.

Comment: Thanks. What about "intensely"? I think it is almost synonymous with "strongly" here.

Comment: Yes it is almost synonymous and so it also won’t work to describe a process like heat transfer. The heat might be intense but not the transfer.